# Reasons for asterisk HangupCause 'Unknown' and 'Normal Clearing'

Tags: asterisk

For some calls I am getting this HangupCause

```
X-Asterisk-HangupCause: Unknown.

X-Asterisk-HangupCauseCode: 0.
```

And for some calls, getting this

```
X-Asterisk-HangupCause: Normal Clearing.

X-Asterisk-HangupCauseCode: 16.
```

Have tried surfing but still having thoughts in mind.

What are the reasons behind these `HangupCause`s?

Answer (score 2):

According to [RFC 6432](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6432), SIP systems MAY send an [ITU Q.850 cause code](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/voice/monitor/configuration/guide/12_4/vt_12_4_book/vt_ccodes_debug.html#wp1007443) in the `Reason` header at call teardown.

Code 16 is, as the log says, a normal call clearing; in other words someone hung up. From the ITU spec:

> 2.2.7.1.10 Cause No. 16 – Normal call clearing
>
> This cause indicates that the call is being cleared because one of the users involved in the call has requested that the call be cleared.
>
> Under normal situations, the source of this cause is not the network.

If it's unknown, then Asterisk doesn't know why the call ended.